# how to remove the shadow that is inserted by default in the images of the phrase?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

i have a drawer with images inside and text, but when selecting a default image it is highlighted and the rest are left with a shadow and i want them all to be the same, not only look good when i select that component.
Next i shadow you an image of what I want and what I get.

[what i want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNURy.png)

[what i have done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33R40.png)

My code:

```
    const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    DIPUTADOS: {
      screen: DiputadosStack,
      navigationOptions
    },
    BLOQUES: {
      screen: BloquesStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerIcon: () => {
          return (
            <Image
              style={styles.Icon}
              source={require("./src/assets/Menu-002-b.png")}
            />
          );
        }
      }
    },
    INTERBLOQUES: {
      screen: InterBloquesStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerIcon: () => {
          return (
            <Image
              style={styles.Icon}
              source={require("./src/assets/Menu-003-b.png")}
            />
          );
        }
      }
    },
    COMISIONES: {
      screen: ComisionesStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerIcon: () => {
          return (
            <Image
              style={styles.Icon}
              source={require("./src/assets/Menu-004-b.png")}
            />
          );
        }
      }
    },
    AUTORIDADES: {
      screen: AutoridadesStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerIcon: () => {
          return (
            <Image
              style={styles.Icon}
              source={require("./src/assets/Menu-005-b.png")}
            />
          );
        }
      }
    },
    "SESIÓN EN VIVO": {
      screen: SesionEnVivoStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerIcon: () => {
          return (
            <Image
              style={styles.Icon}
              source={require("./src/assets/Menu-006-b.png")}
            />
          );
        }
      }
    },
    "DIPUTADOS TV": {
      screen: DiputadosTVStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerIcon: () => {
          return (
            <Image
              style={styles.Icon}
              source={require("./src/assets/Menu-007-b.png")}
            />
          );
        }
      }
    },
    REGLAMENTOS: {
      screen: PDFReglamentosStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerIcon: () => {
          return (
            <Image
              style={styles.Icon}
              source={require("./src/assets/Menu-008-b.png")}
            />
          );
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent,
    drawerWidth: width * 0.63,
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: blue,
      inactiveTintColor: grey,
      itemsContainerStyle: {
        textAlign: "center"
      },
      labelStyle: {
        fontFamily: "RobotoCondensed-Regular",
        fontWeight: "400",
        fontSize: 17,
        marginLeft: -5
      },
      iconContainerStyle: {
        alignItems: "center"
      }
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `overlayColor`.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html#drawernavigatorconfig

```
{
    overlayColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)', // if you wannt no color, you can write 'transparent'.
    contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent,
    drawerWidth: width * 0.63,
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: blue,
      inactiveTintColor: grey,
      itemsContainerStyle: {
        textAlign: "center"
      },
      labelStyle: {
        fontFamily: "RobotoCondensed-Regular",
        fontWeight: "400",
        fontSize: 17,
        marginLeft: -5
      },
      iconContainerStyle: {
        alignItems: "center"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: what changes  this is the shadow of the bottom of the drawer and what , i want is the shadow that appears inside the drawer when i select a component and the others are  left with a shadow or at least the image or the icon that i have